# Optimizing DataTable by removing duplicate entries

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable, c#-3.0

I have a DataTable shown below:

```
  RefID     RefDescription      ReferenceUrl                  SortOrder
    0       Interdiscip       http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/      1
    0       Entropy 20133     http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300     2
    0       Interdiscip       http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/      3
    0       Agriculture       http://www1.agric.gov.ab.ca/      4
    0       Interdiscip       http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/      5
```

In the above dataset if we have  value of RefDescription and ReferenceUrl are same remove those duplicate rows and keep the single row, also append the numbers to it, according to sort Order.

Here, in the above dataSet-- RefDescription: Interdiscip is repeated three times and also it has ReferenceUrl same. so i want the following output as dataset.

Result i want:

```
 RefID     RefDescription      ReferenceUrl                  SortOrder
   0       3,5 Interdiscip    http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/      1
   0        Entropy 20133     http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300     2
   0        Agriculture       http://www1.agric.gov.ab.ca/      4
```

> Note:RefDescription and ReferenceUrl both should have same values in
>   this scenarios otherwise no need to remove and append.

C# Code: i Tried

```
protected void   Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowcount = 0;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("ReferenceData");
        dt.Columns.Add("ReferenceID");
        dt.Columns.Add("ReferenceDescription");
        dt.Columns.Add("ReferenceUrl");
        dt.Columns.Add("SortOrder");
        dt.Rows.Add("0","Interdiscip","http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/","1");
        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Entropy 20133", "http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300", "2");
        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Interdiscip", "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "3");
        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Agriculture", "http://www1.agric.gov.ab.ca/", "4");
        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Interdiscip", "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "5");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtOut = null;
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "ReferenceDescription,ReferenceUrl";
        dtOut = dv.ToTable();

        for (int t = 0; t < dtOut.Rows.Count; t++)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int count = 0;
            int sortorder = 0;
            string space = null;
            string x = dtOut.Rows[t][1].ToString();
            string y = dtOut.Rows[t][2].ToString();
            sortorder = Convert.ToInt32(dtOut.Rows[rowcount][3]);
            for (int j = 0; j < dtOut.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (x == dtOut.Rows[i][1].ToString() && y == dtOut.Rows[i][2].ToString())
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count > 1)
                    {
                        sortorder = Convert.ToInt32(dtOut.Rows[i][3]);
                        space += sortorder + " ";
                        dtOut.Rows[i].Delete();
                        dtOut.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                }

                i++;
            }
            dtOut.Rows[rowcount][1] = space + x;
            rowcount++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Btw, you have shown what you've tried but you haven't mentioned what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
var grps = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
           let RefDescription = row.Field<string>("RefDescription")
           let ReferenceUrl = row.Field<string>("ReferenceUrl")
           group row by new { RefDescription, ReferenceUrl } into groups
           select groups;
dt = grps.Select(g => 
     {
        DataRow first = g.First();
        if (g.Skip(1).Any())
        {
            // duplicates
            string otherSortOrders = String.Join(",", g.Skip(1).Select(r => r.Field<int>("SortOrder")));
            first.SetField("RefDescription", string.Format("{0} {1}",
                otherSortOrders,
                g.Key.RefDescription));
        }
        return first;
     })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

or with one query in pure method syntax (i prefer a combination):

```
dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new {
        RefDescription = r.Field<string>("RefDescription"),
        ReferenceUrl = r.Field<string>("ReferenceUrl")
    })
    .Select(grp =>
    {
        DataRow first = grp.First();
        if (grp.Skip(1).Any())
        {
            // duplicates
            string otherSortOrders = String.Join(",", grp.Skip(1).Select(r => r.Field<int>("SortOrder")));
            first.SetField("RefDescription", string.Format("{0} {1}",
                otherSortOrders,
                grp.Key.RefDescription));
        }
        return first;
    }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: wat?? i didnt get that ..C#3 tag..??

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816728/modifying-and-updating-linkhref-which-is-bind-to-the-repeater-from-datatable ..and please give some solution..

Comment: @Pranav: in .NET 3.5 there was no overload of [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` but only one which takes a `String[]`. So you can use `ToArrray` first: `String.Join(",", g.Skip(1).Select(r => r.Field<int>("SortOrder").ToString()).ToArray())`

Comment: Can we trim the spaces when comparing the strings with LINQ..??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936466/merge-2-or-more-rows-of-a-column-if-other-column-has-same-values-text-in-sqlserv

Comment: what if i dont want to use group by...?

Comment: @Pranav: then you need a different apporach. Can you be more specific?

Comment: here what we have done is by grouping those 2 columns we are getting 1 of them as the are same...but i want both of them to be in datatable

Comment: @Pranav: i'm afraid that you need to post a question with a meaningful title and desciption and also a little sample. Otherwise it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

I did few changes try this now if it solves the issue...

```
        int rowcount = 0;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("ReferenceData");
        dt.Columns.Add("ReferenceID");
        dt.Columns.Add("ReferenceDescription");
        dt.Columns.Add("ReferenceUrl");
        dt.Columns.Add("SortOrder");

        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Interdiscip", "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "1");
        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Entropy 20133", "http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300", "2");
        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Interdiscip", "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "3");
        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Agriculture", "http://www1.agric.gov.ab.ca/", "4");
        dt.Rows.Add("0", "Interdiscip", "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "5");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dtOut = null;
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.Sort = "ReferenceDescription,ReferenceUrl";
        dtOut = dv.ToTable();

        dt = dv.ToTable();

        for (int t = 0; t < dtOut.Rows.Count; t++)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int count = 0;
            int sortorder = 0;
            string space = null;
            string x = dtOut.Rows[t][1].ToString();
            string y = dtOut.Rows[t][2].ToString();
            sortorder = Convert.ToInt32(dtOut.Rows[rowcount][3]);
            for (int j = 0; j < dtOut.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (x == dtOut.Rows[j][1].ToString() && y == dtOut.Rows[j][2].ToString())
                {
                    count = dtOut.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.Field<string>("ReferenceDescription").EndsWith(x) && s.Field<string>("ReferenceUrl") == y).Count();

                    //count++;
                    if (count > 1)
                    {
                        sortorder = Convert.ToInt32(dtOut.Rows[j][3]);
                        space += sortorder + " ";
                        dtOut.Rows[j].Delete();
                        dtOut.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                }

                i++;
            }
            dtOut.Rows[rowcount][1] = space + x;
            rowcount++;
        }
```