# Rows to comma separated values using XML tag

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables named 'Categories' and 'CSTagContent' shown below with data...

**TABLE 1: 'Categories'**

```
CategoryID  PostID  <----Categories Table
 1148       581771  
 1183       581771  
 1184       581771
```

**TABLE 2: 'CSTagContent'**

```
ID   TagContent       StartDate   EndDate   CategoryID      TagTitle     <---CSTagContent Table

 1 <blockquote><p>     2014-11-08 2014-11-14  1148       
   <a href="abc.com">
   </p></blockquote>
 2 <blockquote><p>     2014-11-25 2014-12-05  1183     <h1>Aging Title</h1> 
   <a href="abc.com">
   </p></blockquote>
 3 <blockquote><p>     2014-11-25 2014-11-27  1184     <h1>Allergies Title</h1> 
   <a href="abc.com">
   </p></blockquote>
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT 
    st.TagContent, st.TagTitle              
FROM 
    Categories cpc 
INNER JOIN
    CSTagContent st ON st.CategoryID = cpc.CategoryID
WHERE 
    cpc.PostID = 581771 
    AND st.TagContent IS NOT NULL 
    AND st.TagContent <> ''                                               
    AND GETDATE() > st.StartDate  
    AND GETDATE() < DATEADD(dd, 1, st.EndDate)
```

**Current output:**

```
 TagContent             TagTitle

<blockquote><p>     
<a href="abc.com">    <h1>Aging Title</h1>
</p></blockquote>

<blockquote><p>      <h1>Allergies Title</h1> 
<a href="abc.com">
</p></blockquote>
```

In above output `TagContent` has same values for both rows, so i want it distinct and `TagTitle` should be appended or merged with '&' with the other row/rows as shown below...

**Expected output:**

```
   TagContent                    TagTitle

  <blockquote><p>     
  <a href="abc.com">    <h1>Aging Title</h1>&<h1>Allergies Title</h1> 
  </p></blockquote>
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: This looks like a version of [the `GROUP_CONCAT`/ LISTAGG hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server) with an ampersand delimiter.

Comment: @stuartLC: I have tried but cant get as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SAMPLE TABLES**

```
SELECT * INTO Categories
FROM
(
   SELECT 1148 CategoryId, 581771 PostId
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1183 CategoryId, 581771 PostId
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1184 CategoryId, 581771 PostId   
)TAB


SELECT * INTO TagContent
FROM
(
SELECT 1 [Id], '<blockquote><p><a href="abc.com"></p></blockquote>' TagContent ,    '2014-11-08' StartDate, '2014-11-14' EndDate,  1148 CategoryID, NULL TagTitle     

UNION ALL   
SELECT  2, '<blockquote><p><a href="abc.com"></p></blockquote>',     '2014-11-25', '2014-12-05',  1183,     '<h1>Aging Title</h1>' 


UNION ALL
SELECT  3, '<blockquote><p><a href="abc.com"></p></blockquote>',     '2014-11-25', '2014-11-27',  1184,     '<h1>Allergies Title</h1>' 
)TAB
```

Now we convert `TagTitle` to Ambersand seperated valuesfor the same `TagContent`. Since XML format is used we need to replace `&gt, &lt and`&amp`to <, > and &`.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT DISTINCT TagContent,STUFF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT '&' + TagTitle
        FROM TagContent T2 
        WHERE ST.TagContent=T2.TagContent 
        FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000),'&lt;','<'),'&gt;','>'),'&amp;','&'),'amp;',''),1,'') TagTitle
        FROM Categories CPC
        JOIN TagContent ST ON CPC.CategoryId=ST.CategoryId
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cf16/1)**

Comment: Output is like this: &<h1></h1>&#x0D; <h1> </h1>&#x0D; <h1>Aging Title</h1>&<h1></h1>  <h1> </h1>  <h1>Allergies Title</h1>

Comment: Can u give some sample data on which its showing the above output? @Pranav

Comment: The query is working fine even in **SQLFIDDLE**. Please update with some more data and the query on which you are fetching data. @Pranav

Comment: <h1></h1>  <h1> </h1>  <h1>Aging Title</h1>                      <h1></h1>  <h1> </h1>  <h1>Allergies Title</h1> there are the actual TagTitle..

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you edit your question and add the TagTitle in the question? @Pranav

Comment: i get the following result set in SQL Server 2008:                 &<h1>Aging Title</h1>&<h1>Allergies Title</h1>               (Ampersand is appended at the begining which is not required)

Comment: Can u give some sample code in question on which u r working now? @Pranav